# 16.04 LIbreoffice starts on startup

Tags: libreoffice, startup, 16.04

I upgraded from 14.04 yesterday, all going well generally but one weird thing; when I log on, Libreoffice Write starts automatically. It's not in my startup applications, and never has been, so what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Open LibreWriter and check Tools / Options / LibreOffice / Memory if the quickstarter is enabled and uncheck it. I had such an issue.

Comment: It wasn't checked, but I checked and unchecked just in case, then logged out and back in. LibreWriter didn't start but Abiword did!